# Pass function to directive

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Here is my directive:

```
module app.directives {

    interface IDmDeleteIconController {
        doAction(): void;
    }

    class DmDeleteIconController implements IDmDeleteIconController {

        static $inject = ['$scope'];
        constructor(public $scope:any) {
        }

        doAction() {
            console.log('1');
            this.$scope.dmAction();
        }
    }

    export class DmDeleteIcon implements ng.IDirective {

        templateUrl = './app/common/directives/deleteIcon/deleteIcon.html';
        controller = DmDeleteIconController;
        controllerAs = 'dmDeleteIconVm';

        scope = {
            dmAction: '&'
        };

        link = (scope: any, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes, ctrl: any) => {
            console.log('2');
            scope.dmAction();
        }

        static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
            const directive = () => new DmDeleteIcon();
            directive.$inject = [];
            return directive;
        }
    }

    angular.module('myApp').directive('dmDeleteIcon', DmDeleteIcon.factory());
}
```

Here I am trying to use it:

```
dm-delete-icon(dm-action="console.log('hello');")
```

When I am open page I'll get `2` in the console (from `link` function), but I don't get the `hello` from the function I have passed to directive.

Why and how can I fix it?

*Update:*

Here is a directive template:

```
a.item-detail-delete-icon(class="form-image-link" href="" ng-click="dmDeleteIconVm.doAction()")
```

Here is HTML to which my Jade compile:

```
<dm-delete-icon dm-action="console.log('hello');"></dm-delete-icon>
```

**Update 2:**

I was trying to use it like this:

```
<dm-delete-icon dm-action="vm.foo()"></dm-delete-icon>
```

where:

```
    foo(): void {
        console.log("hello");       
    }
```

the function in the controller.

**Update 3:**

If I am trying to debug this code I will get this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you post the entire html tag where you use it?

Comment: do you mean the directive template or HTML which I will get from my Jade? I have added both of them to my question

Comment: You are not supplying a function to the attribute `dm-action`. The `console.log` is not a function, so how this should be called with `dmAction()` afterwards?

Comment: I have updated my question.  I was trying to pass controller's function before and it didn't work for me.

Comment: @toskv, I have added debugger screenshots. May be it will help to find the problem.

Comment: @toskv, I have find the problem.  I need to add `;`. So `dm-action="vm.foo()"` should be `dm-action="vm.foo();"`.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're passing to the directive an expression `console.log('hello');` that will be executed on parent controller scope.

This basically means you'd need to have `console` object attached to scope and under that object a method `log`. Angular expressions don't work with globals (`console` in this case) automatically.

Simply ensure that the expression you pass to the directive is a valid angular expression and that should work. For example - create new method on app scope called `myConsoleLog` that prints something to the console and change the attribute value for the directive to `dm-action="myConsoleLog();"`

Comment: I have updated my question.  I was trying to pass controller's function before and it didn't work for me.

Comment: I have added debugger screenshots. May be it will help to find the problem.

Comment: I have find the problem.  I need to add `;`. So `dm-action="vm.foo()"` should be `dm-action="vm.foo();"`